# How to block user login before activation asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am new to C#. I have Activation Data Type Bit in my database default value 0.

My question is how can I block user to login before activation email send 
after registration is completed the activation is null in database but still user can login how can I fix this problem please help.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegisterConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where UserName='" + UserName.Text + "'";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
        conn.Close();
        if (temp == 1)
        {
            conn.Open();
            string checkPasswordQuery = "select password from UserData where UserName='" + UserName.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand passComm = new SqlCommand(checkPasswordQuery, conn);
            string password = passComm.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");

            if (password == Password.Text && UserName.Text == "Admin" )
            {
                Session["New"] = UserName.Text;
                Response.Redirect("~/Admin/UserManager.aspx");
            }
            if (password == Password.Text)
            {
                Session["New"] = UserName.Text;
                Response.Redirect("~/Account/UserPage.aspx");
            }
            else
            {
                invalidlbl.Text = "Please check your username and password";
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the image of my database:

[image]

Comment: Is this a school assignment? The reason I'm asking is your code has few security vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said *activation is null in database*. So, when user tried to login, fetch and check if the `activation` is still `null` in database and if so then just so a message to user saying *activate your account first* and redirect him/her to home page.

**EDIT:** per your comment, not going to give you full code but here is an example of what I am saying. BTW, consider using SQL Parameter to avoid SQL Injection attack.

```
        string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where UserName=@uname and activation != null";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
        com.Parameters.Add("@uname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserName.Text.Trim();
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar());

if(temp > 0)
{
  // do processing
}
else
{
  // not activated ... throw alert
}
```

Comment: how can i fetch can you please show me the right way ?

Comment: the activation is null but still  user can login how can i fix this problem

Comment: Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'dream01 and Activation != null i got this error

Comment: You will have to take care of the rest implementation. Otherwise, where is your learning? I have shown you enough to get started.

Comment: string checkuser = "select count(*) from UserData where UserName='" + UserName.Text + " and Activation != null"; is some thing wrong in my code ?

Comment: Yes, it's open for SQL Injection attack. Consider reading about SQL Injection attack and ADO.NET.

Comment: is there any way to fix this problem ?

Comment: can you suggest any link where i can find useful method ?

Comment: You should be using ASP.Net Identity to handle your security, it's far more secure than doing what you're doing. You're open to SQL injection, passwords in your database aren't hashed, watch some Identity training videos.

Comment: i know how to hashed password i'm also using GUID for user but this is not my problem my problem is i dont want to allow user when user is not activated .

Comment: @Apsdevs00698, well, you are getting that error cause mostly your textbox value contains that `'` character. So, either you refrain from putting a single quote or replace it like `UserName.Text.Replace("'","")`

Comment: no this is not the case this is UserName.Text.Replace("Space","") to none

Comment: when activation is !=null both user can login activated none activated